# How do I use is or are in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which is the correct sentence: Reading newspapers is a good way to build your vocabulary. OR Reading newspapers are a good way to build your vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

The singular activity *reading* is the subject of the sentence, as Jim has pointed out. The number of items being read is irrelevant.

Answer (score -4):

I think the first would be best. Like *family* the word *newspapers* can be considered already plural and can take a singular verb.

Comment: The subject is not newspapers: it’s reading:  *Reading is a good way...”